# Select and Alter foreground image declared in activity_fullscreen Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

just started making an android app, its very simple I just need it done quickly. I am trying to change the alpha of an image that I set as the foreground image in activity_fullscreen.xml  I am trying to make the foreground image fade in and out.

I understand how to set the alpha with setAlpha but I dont understand how to select the foreground image with

```
Drawable guts = (Drawable) ..........
```

What do I use to select the foreground image of

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:keepScreenOn="true" android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="50sp" android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/dummy_content" />

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="590dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/guts"
    android:background="@drawable/red">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls" style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay" android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <Button android:id="@+id/dummy_button" style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:text="@string/dummy_button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry can't post comments yet)
Your xml doesn't show any image, that could be a start...

Otherwise, you could have something like :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/background"
        android:src="@drawable/background_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/foreground"
        android:src="@drawable/foreground_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And then just go :

```
//Get the ImageView
ImageView foregroundImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foreground);
//Set it's alpha the way you want
foregroundImage.setAlpha(0.6f);
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the Drawable of the FrameLayout, you have to first get reference to the layout. To get a reference, assign an id to your FrameLayout and then do the following:

```
FramLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id_here);
```

Once you have this, you can do the following to get the drawable:

```
Drawable drawable = fl.getForeground();
```

You can read more about this method at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#getForeground()

Using this, you can directly reference your drawable.